# How to subtract days to a Timestamp in CrateDB SQL query?

Tags: cratedb

How can i subtract days to a timestamp in CrateDB SQL query?

Exist something similar to this?

```
TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract `INTERVAL` from `TIMESTAMP`, but before any matematichal operation you need to [CAST the datatype](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/5.1/general/ddl/data-types.html#type-casting), you can do it in this way:

```
SELECT now() - CAST('14 day' AS INTERVAL)
```

Or the same function of above, but in a contracted way

```
SELECT now() - '14 day'::INTERVAL;
```

As a string to be `CAST` to an `INTERVAL` you can use a number followed by any of this:

- `second`
- `minute`
- `hour`
- `day`
- `week`
- `month`
- `quarter`
- `year`

Answer (score 3):

Don't think there is a built in function but you could do something like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1000*60*60*24*14) LIMIT 100
```

in this example (1000 * 60 * 60) * *24* * **14** (24 is to get days and 14 is your number of days)

NB. You can also cast dates into timestamp and perform similar functionality

```
SELECT  ABS(cast('2019-01-1' AS TIMESTAMP) - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) / (1000*60*60*24) LIMIT 100
```

this will get you a number of days between now and 1st of January

[So far that's all what they have in their docs](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/builtins/scalar.html#date-and-time-functions)